# Fetching из сущностей, обьединенных отношениями

Tags: data-structures, objective-c, ios, coredata, база-данных

Имею две сущности `Customer` и `City`, от `Customer` к `City` я указал many-to-one relationship с названием `cities` чтобы фетчить его проперти с названием `name`, обратно указан one-to-many relationship и они определены как inverse. Для фетча использую:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    self.managedObjectContext = [[PTDataManager sharedManager] managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Customer"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Собственно все проперти `Customer'ов` я таким образом получаю, но значение проперти `name` вытягиваемое через relationship `cities` является (null). Для проверки наличия данных в `name` использую метод:

> -(City *)city {
>     return (City* )[[PTDataFetchHelper sharedInstance] entityForName:@"City"
> withServerID:self.city_server_id
> inContext:[self
> managedObjectContext]]; }

определенный в `NSManagedObject`-сабклассе для сущности `Customer`. Таким образом данные выводятся, но это работает очень медленно, tableView в которую выводятся данные при этом начинает сильно тормозить. Да и хочется сделать это нормально, используя связи.
Таким образом вопросы:

- при указанном фетче из базы тянутся только `Customer`-объекты или и все с ним связанные отношениями?
- если нет то нужно ли указывать предикат для такого фетча (с целью вытянуть все данные из пропертей связанных сущностей)?
- Если предикат все же нужен, как он может выглядеть учитывая что мне нужно вытянуть все объекты по данной проперти никак не ограничивая фетч?

**UPD:**

код используемый для вывода данных в ячейку таблицы

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    .....

    customer = (Client *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     // customer's full name
    cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", customer.lastname, customer.firstname, client.middlename];

    // customer's city
    cell.cityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", customer.cities.name];

     .....

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Не чувствую себя достаточно уверенным в этом вопросе, поэтому пишу в комментарий по порядку: 1) Во-первых из написанного неясно по поводу name - зачем идет проверка на наличие данных - потому что нужны только те записи у которых name непустой? Или вам не удается вытянуть имена, потому что они оказываются пустыми, хотя должны быть непустыми?

Comment: 2) В Core Data есть такая штука Faults - советую посмотреть о ней документацию - я понял этот момент не до конца, и временно считаю, что это то же самое что lazy loading в Rails - то есть при фетче тянутся грубо говоря только ID объектов Customer а все остальное подтягивается из базы по требованию - то есть объекты связанные отношениями НЕ ТЯНУТСЯ, если только вы их прямо не затребуете.

Comment: 3) Если вы уточните то, что я написал в пункте 1) будет легче ответить на ваши два последних пункта - но по умолчанию ответ такой - должно работать просто по точке, без предикатов. Готов продолжить обсуждение вопроса.

Comment: Станислав мое имя) Давайте еще уточним вашу схему - мне кажется, у вас ошибка в описании схемы: "one-to-one relationship с названием cities чтобы фетчить его проперти с названием name, обратно указан one-to-many relationship" - не может быть чтобы на одной стороне один-к-одному, а на другой один-ко-многим, короче one-to-one и cities во множественном числе друг другу противоречат, верно? Сорри за дотошность, просто явно легче будем с вами совместно думать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У меня исчерпался лимит для комментирования, поэтому пишу в ответ.

1) Вы можете по-быстрому скрафтить болваночный проект, который воспроизводит вашу ситуацию, выложить его и добавить на него ссылку в ваш вопрос? Так было бы проще обсуждать, хотя и займет у вас дополнительное время.

2) Покажите ваш код `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, или соответствующий в другом месте код, где вы обращаетесь к результатам из базы?

Мое предположение состоит в том, что в вашем случае все просто должно работать просто по точкам без всяких дополнительных предикатов в NSFetchRequest, поэтому я хочу увидеть, что именно вы делаете с результатами из базы (NSFetch results).

**ФИНАЛЬНОЕ ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

После обсуждения этого вопроса с его автором в скайпе мы совместно выяснили, что все мои основные предварительные предположения о возможных проблемах оказались верны:

Во-первых, в схеме .xcdatamodeld Xcode проекта у автора были неправильно расставлены отношения между Customer и City (точнее - не были расставлены совсем, вместо них стояли обычные геттеры и сеттеры в классах, без декларации в схеме!, с соответствующими именами вроде cities). В конечном счете оказалось, что Customer все-таки имеет **один** город, то есть соответствующие строки у экземпляров Customer приняли в итоге вид customer.**city**.name (city в единственном числе).

Во-вторых мы написали код склеивающий отношения между Customer и City (сразу же после приема соответствующего им JSON) на уровне Core Data. Вот типичная схема "склейки" - перевода JSON в Core Data:

customer создается из JSON, city создается из JSON, и, наконец, customer.city = city и после этого оказывается, что обе сущности CoreData связаны между собой.

После этих изменений весь оригинальный код заработал просто "по точкам" без всяких дополнительных предикатов, при этом, очевидно, был значительно достигнут значительный speed-up (то есть прирост в скорости) всего процесса - UI приложение перестало тормозить и начало летать. Добро восторжествовало, Ура!

Comment: минутку,  добавлю в -cellForRowAtIndexPath: добавлю в описание вопроса

Comment: Спасибо, вижу. Следующим очевидным этапом будет спросить вас - а вы точно уверены, что ваши отношения сохраняются в базу верным образом. Производили ли вы просто проверку того, в каком виде получаются в базе объекты после парсинга JSON? То есть это ТОЧНО, что у вас база хранит верную схему и все готово к фетчингу?

Comment: Да и еще добавлю - что очень сильно подозрительной выглядит запись customer.cities.name (с самого начала выглядела просто теперь это стало явно). Должно быть или так - customer.city.name, т.е. у заказчика есть один город и вы берете его имя, или у заказчика есть много городов, но вы берете имя какого-то особого города из этих многих customer.cities.first.name или customer.specificCityOfManyCities.name.

Comment: То есть возникает переспросить вас про схему отношений которую вы выбрали - у заказчика есть один город? Если да, то назовите соответствующее отношение city, а если много, тогда ваша запись должна выглядеть как-то точно иначе, чем customer.cities.name.

Comment: Я чувствую, что слишком много текста пишется. Мой скайп есть в профиле - готов с легкостью обсудить ваш вопрос по скайпу. Опыт общения по скайпу показал, что вопросы ХэшКода разруливаются гораздо быстрее и эффективнее ;), а в сюда на ХК вписывается уже готовый ответ/решение с подробными разъяснениями.

Comment: Выражается Огромная благодарность с вечным занесением в карму по итогам решения задачи довольно простым и элегантным способом. Большое спасибо за затраченное время и силы, Станислав!